# zend framework 2 display if form element is required in view

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2, zend-form

In my view I would like to add a message to indicate if a form element is required. I am using the inputFilter to set validation options which all works fine, but I cannot find any way of accessing these options in the view before the form is posted (after i can access the messages).

```
$this->add(array(
                    'name'     => 'title',
                    'required' => true,
                    'filters'  => array(
                            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                    ),
                    'validators' => array(
                            array(
                            'name' =>'NotEmpty', 
                                'options' => array(
                                    'messages' => array(
                                        \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'Please enter a title (e.g \'Property\')' 
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                            array(
                                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                                    'options' => array(
                                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
            ));
```

Comment: about to give it a go, thanks

Answer (score 0):

in your view it should be something like:

```
$form->getInputFilter()->get("fieldName")->isRequired();
```

or

```
$form->getInputFilter()->get("fieldName")->getRequired();
```

I don't remember

**Workaround:**

You could set the attribute required (I think you've already done this), and then add a small jquery that will append the message, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
     $("*:required")
        //Optional add red boder--
        .css('border','1px solid #FF0000');
        //--Optional add red boder
           .closest('label')
                  .append('<br /><span><?= $this->translate('This field is mandatory') ?></span>');
});
```

Unfortunately I can reproduce your issue, maybe if you post the controller code I can see if there is something else wrong.

Comment: I get very odd behaviour with this, for a given element, prior to posting it returns false, after posting with an empty value it returns true.

Comment: I've edited my answer suggesting a Jquery workaround.

Comment: Thanks bruno, I will be adding a full layer of js validation at a later date but I have a requirement to get it working non js in the first instance. I might just go for hard coding it into the view and just manually sinking it up.